# Wordpress theme from scratch

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, styles

I'm trying to develop a wordpress theme from scratch, but I have som problem with function.php. I want to add additional style scripts like bootstrap and animate.css, but the thing is that they are not loading with the "package" and when I check the links I get style.css before my css folder. If I remove style.css I can se my file in my browser. How do I solve this problem? To remove style.css from the links.

http://localhost/humlan/wp-content/themes/humlan/style.css/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=3.0.3'

THIS IS CODE IN FUNCTION.PHP

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function humlan_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css',false,'3.0.3','all');
wp_enqueue_style( 'prettyPhoto', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/prettyPhoto.css',false,'1.1','all');
wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome.min', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css',false,'1.1','all');
wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/animate.css',false,'1.1','all');
wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/main.css',false,'1.1','all');
wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/css/responsive.css',false,'1.1','all');
wp_enqueue_style( 'humlan-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'humlan-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'humlan-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'humlan_scripts' );
```

Comment: THIS IS CODE IN HEADER.PHP

<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
 <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

 <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

Comment: Please use the *Add Comment* button only for actual comments. You should [edit] your original question to add additional information.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
function load_styles(){
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery-js', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js');
   wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.7', true );
}
```

Instead of loading css from your server, use CDN links that are comparatively faster...

Comment: Yeah! I agree with you but right now I want to use downloaded files and make It work with wordpress style

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` - as that returns the folder of your stylesheet.  What you're using returns the URI of the *actual* stylesheet.